# Javascript: reurns a null in the controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

```
$("body").delegate("#btn-edit-jacket-variation","click",function(){
        var variationid = $(this).data("id");
        var variationname = $(this).data("name");
        var id = $(this).data("idpath");

        $("#edit-id").val(id);
        $("#edit-jacket-id").val(jacketid);
        $('#edit-variation-id').val(variationid);
        $("#edit-variation-name").val(variationname);

        var BASE_URL = $("#hdnBaseUrl").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            data: {id:$(this).data("idpath")},
            url: BASE_URL + '/getsinglepath',
            success: function(data){
                $("#edit-variation-path").val(data["path"]);
            }
        });

        $("#editJacketPathModal").modal("show");
    });
```

In ajax: data:{id:$(this).data("idpath")},
is that right? it returns a null in the controller.

Comment: what $(this).data("idpath") alerts?

Comment: data: {id:id}, I changed it.

Comment: I wanted the value of $(this).data("idpath"). what it alerts???

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use JSON.stringify

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            data: JSON.stringify({id:$(this).data("idpath")}),
            url: BASE_URL + '/getsinglepath',
            success: function(data){
                $("#edit-variation-path").val(data["path"]);
            }
        });
```

> The JSON.stringify() method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON
>   string, optionally replacing values if a replacer function is
>   specified, or optionally including only the specified properties if a
>   replacer array is specified.

Comment: still return null with this error.                                                                      {"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Trying to get property of non-object","file":"C:\\xampp \\htdocs\\daluna_jacket_v2\\app\\controllers\\AdminController.php","line":1269}}

Comment: {"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Trying to get property of non-object","file":"C:\\xampp
\\htdocs\\daluna_jacket_v2\\app\\controllers\\AdminController.php","line":1269}}